# Curl http_code 400

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to send the push Notification but it is getting problem

```
$url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

$fields = array(
    'registration_ids' => $id,
    'data' => $load,
);

$headers = array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
);

// Open connection
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11');  
// Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields, true));
// Execute post

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch);
```

And when I try to see the curl info I see there is http_code 400. I did everything but still I am getting problem and push notification is not working.
Can you guys please help me ? I am stuck here.

```
 Array
(
  [url] => https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send
[content_type] => text/plain; charset=UTF-8
[http_code] => 400
[header_size] => 406
[request_size] => 698
[filetime] => -1
[ssl_verify_result] => 0
[redirect_count] => 0
[total_time] => 0.22549
[namelookup_time] => 0.028427
[connect_time] => 0.030052
[pretransfer_time] => 0.189248
[size_upload] => 382
[size_download] => 41
[speed_download] => 181
[speed_upload] => 1694
[download_content_length] => -1
[upload_content_length] => 382
[starttransfer_time] => 0.225382
[redirect_time] => 0
[certinfo] => Array
    (
    )

[primary_ip] => 172.217.6.234
[primary_port] => 443
[local_ip] => 162.243.229.189
[local_port] => 54327
[redirect_url] => 
)
```

Comment: I am getting in square api curl request the http_code 400 :(

Answer (score 0):

Error 400 means Bad Request. I see in your code, in the $headers array that you have the GOOGLE_API_KEY which is not defined in your script. You also have not defined $id and $load from what I can see.

Firstly, you will need a Google Cloud Messaging API Key, which you can obtain from the [Google Developer's Console](https://console.developers.google.com/project).

Please note that the method which you are employing requires a client side app installed on the mobile device. An alternative would be to send a web-push notification, which pushes the notification to Chrome (or any other compatible web browser), so long as it is running and has any tab open. If this is an option you think is worth looking at, I suggest you look at the following [web-push library on Git-Hub.](https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push-php)

Comment: thanks for your concern but those things are predefined somewhere in project and i have checked that are not the cases...